# return data from Oracle Function?

Tags: c#, function, oracle11g

Hi I have the following function created in Oracle.
i will have to pass date-1 and date-2 parameters into the function and the function should return the another date to me .

please see the code below.

```
create or replace function GETD(p_d1   in date, 
                                p_d2   in date ) return DATE 
   as 
       l_result    DATE; 
   begin 
    SELECT EDIT_Date into l_result FROM qa.employees  WHERE qa.employee_join_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(p_d1, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(p_d2, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND ROWNUM <= 1
    ;
       return l_result; 
  end;
```

i execute the function as below

```
SELECT GETD('27-JUN-12','28-JUN-12') FROM DUAL
```

the function get compiled and while im passing the parameters to execute the function i get the following error "Not a Valid Month".
Could some one please tell me where im going wrong

thanks
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not call `TO_DATE` on a date variable.  If you do that, you force Oracle to first convert the date to a string using the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and then convert the string back to a date using the specified format mask.  If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` happens not to match the specified format mask (and, since the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is controlled by the client, some users and sessions will inevitably have a different date format), you'll get an error.

Assuming your intention was merely to ignore any time component, you should be using the `trunc` function instead.

```
create or replace function GETD(p_d1   in date, 
                                p_d2   in date ) 
  return DATE 
as 
  l_result    DATE; 
begin 
  SELECT EDIT_Date 
    into l_result 
    FROM qa.employees  
   WHERE qa.employee_join_date BETWEEN trunc(p_d1) AND trunc(p_d2) 
     AND ROWNUM <= 1;

  return l_result; 
end;
```

The presence of a `rownum <= 1` condition seems a bit odd-- it seems unlikely that you really want to fetch an arbitrary row from the table that matches the `employee_join_date` criteria.  Not knowing the requirements, it seems likely that you want to do something deterministic that fetches the row with the minimum (or maximum) `edit_date`.

Second, when you call the function, you should pass in `DATE` parameters rather than passing in strings and letting Oracle implicitly convert the strings to dates using the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.  If you use date literals

```
SELECT GETD(date '2012-06-27', date '2012-06-28') 
  FROM DUAL
```

or convert the strings to dates explicitly using a `TO_DATE`

```
SELECT GETD(to_date('27-JUN-12', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('28-JUN-12', 'DD-MON-RR')) 
  FROM DUAL
```

then your call will work regardless of the client's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.